# Loopcuts ignore surface on messed up mesh

Tags: mesh, topology

I recently started my first real project in Blender. An AK47. Most parts I managed to model decently. Now I reached a point where I don't know what to do. I got stuck on the parts that are complex and molded from a single piece of metal. The Sights looks good to me now, but if I add a sub surface modifier it screws it all up since loop cuts won't behave in the way I need them to. I tried recalculating the normals, remove doubles. I know that I did something wrong here. I just don't know the "correct" way of structuring this mesh for it to work.

[image: loop cut not on some faces]

Comment: It's because of ngons. You need to have quad based topology to correctly use Subsuf modifier.

Comment: If you want to still cut through your geometry despite having Ngons you can use the knife tool. Hit "K" for the knife tool then at the bottom of the 3D view it will show tool tips hit "Z" to cut through and then hit "C" to constrain it to a straight line.

Comment: I tried that and I somewhat got around my problem! Thanks! :)